# How to make mirror of current running wordpress site on same server?

Tags: mysql, php, wordpress

**For example:**

I have a wordpress site(blog) on **www.xxxxxx.com**

I want to **upgrade some plugins** and **WP version** of site but before it i want to check all things on a mirror version.

How to make a mirror backup site of currently running site on same server like **www.xxxxxx.com/testing-site/**?

whatever i will do on mirror site, should not effect to live site.

I will delete mirror after successfully checking all upgrade on it? and will upgrade WP version and plugin on live site.

I don't want to loose any content, comment on live site(blog).

My hosting is on **PHP** based server and my hosting control panel is **cpanel**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a copy of the database.
- Create a new database user.
- Make a copy of the Wordpress Web tree
- Point `wp-config.php` to the database copy
- If desired, setup a separate VirtualHost for the copy
- Test your changes

Be careful, ideally this would be a separate server.

Comment: "ideally this would be a separate server" but not technically it should be possible on same server.

Comment: huh?  When you make a mistake and mess up the primary site, you'll understand the benefits of a separate server.

Comment: The procedure I provided can be applied to your single server.

Comment: @Warner - I'm very agree with you. but the problem is i don't have another server

Comment: @Warner - Can i use same database for both sites main and testing. because in testing site i will not add any new article or comment. i will just upgrade wordpress versions and plugins and i think it will not write anything in database.

Comment: You could but if there are database schema changes, it would potentially break the old version.  Additionally, you risk the data.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Warner- please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416768/wordpress-test-site-goes-to-main-site-url-how-to-solve

Comment: Typeonerror has some pretty solid recommendations.  I'd use a separate vhost, such as test.domain.com, as that would simplify things.  What's the issue?

Comment: @Warner - The issue is "I copied all data of public_html/ folder to public_html/test/" and then if i open public_html/test/ then it opens a error page of public_html/

Comment: @Warner - see details in my last comment at this answer of @Tim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416768/wordpress-test-site-goes-to-main-site-url-how-to-solve/3416961#3416961